# How can I edit an xml file that is stored in S3 without using a temp directory?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a config file in an S3 bucket that needs to be modified by adding the response from ec2.describe_subnets and sent to an api endpoint. Is there a way to automate this process using Lambda to get the file from S3 without having to save it to a temp directory?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to automate this process using Lambda to get the file from S3 without having to save it to a temp directory?

If you're asking about *modifying the contents of the S3 Object*, then the answer is no, it's not possible because S3 doesn't support that kind of operation. The only thing you can do is overwrite the entire object (ie, not just parts of it).

If you're asking about *overwriting the S3 Object with new contents*, then yes, it is possible to do it "without having to save it to a temp directory" if you do it in memory, for example.

Download the object from S3 without writing it to storage, make the changes in memory, and re-upload it to S3. If the file size is too big to fully store in memory, you can do it in a streaming fashion, too (i.e., initiate the download, for each chunk you download you make the necessary changes, and upload the modified chunk with a multipart upload, clear up the memory, repeat, etc).

As a final note, do keep in mind that S3 supports only eventual consistency for updates. This means that after you update the object, subsequent reads may still download the previous version. If whatever is consuming the file cannot properly deal with that, you'll probably need a different approach (i.e., don't overwrite, but write a new object with a new key, and send that new key to the consumer; or just use storage system that does support strong consistency, such as DynamoDB).